# How to return a list from a pos tag column?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

these are my modules:

```py
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
import re
from collections import defaultdict,Counter
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import os
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize,sent_tokenize
```

I have a df that is similar to this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'comments': ['Daniel is really cool',
                                'Daniel is the most',
                                'We had such a',
                                'Very professional operation',
                                'Lots of bookcases']})
```

Then I pass through the following:

```py
df['tokenized'] = df['comments'].apply(word_tokenize)
df['tagged'] = df['tokenized'].apply(pos_tag)
df['lower_tagged'] = df['tokenized'].apply(lambda lt: [word.lower() for word in lt]).apply(pos_tag)
```

The column I am interested in is the lower tagged column

```py
0    [(daniel, NN), (is, VBZ), (really, RB), (cool,...
1    [(daniel, NN), (is, VBZ), (the, DT), (most, RBS)]
2         [(we, PRP), (had, VBD), (such, JJ), (a, DT)]
3    [(very, RB), (professional, JJ), (operation, NN)]
4            [(lots, NNS), (of, IN), (bookcases, NNS)]
```

I am trying to implement a function which returns a list of the 1,000 most frequent nouns in the lower_tagged column.

The expected outcome should look something like:

```py
nouns = ['daniel', 'operation', 'bookcases', 'lots']
```

One method I have tried is as follows:

```py
lower_tag = df['lower_tagged']
print([t[0] for t in lower_tag if t[1] == 'NN'])
```

However, this just returns an empty list. Another method i've tried:

```py
def list_nouns(df):
    s = lower_tag
    nouns = [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(s)) if pos.startswith('NN')]
    return nouns
```

However, I get this error: `expected string or bytes-like object`

Apologises for the long post - any suggestions would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a while!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new DataFrame with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) and [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html#pandas-series-tolist) then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) on a boolean index created with [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas-series-str-startswith), then [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html#pandas-dataframe-nlargest) to get only the value counts for each word:

```
top_n_words = 2
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    df['lower_tagged'].explode().tolist(),
    columns=['word', 'part_of_speech']
)
nouns = new_df[
    new_df['part_of_speech'].str.startswith('NN')
].value_counts().reset_index().nlargest(top_n_words, 0)['word'].tolist()
```

---

Or [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) then use [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas-series-str-startswith) accessor and [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas-series-str-startswith) to create a boolean index on the series then [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html#pandas-dataframe-nlargest) to get only the value counts for each word:

```
top_n_words = 2
s = df['lower_tagged'].explode()
nouns = (
    s[s.str[-1].str.startswith('NN')].str[0]
        .value_counts()
        .reset_index()
        .nlargest(top_n_words, 'lower_tagged')['index'].tolist()
)
```

---

Just change `top_n_words` to select however many words are needed.

`nouns` for `top_n_words = 2`:

```
['daniel', 'bookcases']
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, how can I edit the second method to return only the 1,000 most frequent nouns?

Comment: I missed that in your question the first time. I have `top_n_words` set to `2` here, because of the small sample size of data, but just change it to `1000` for your use case. I updated both options.